# Filtering list of XElements against a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my xml file :

```
<items>
  <item code="1">
    <info1>LOREM</info1>
    <info2>IPSUM</info2>
    <info3>DOLOR</info3>
  </item>
  <item code="2">
    <info1>LOREM</info1>
    <info2>AMET</info2>
    <info3>CONSECTETUER</info3>
  </item>
  <item code="3">
    <info1>LOREM</info1>
    <info2>IPSUM</info2>
    <info3>CONSECTETUER</info3>
  </item>
</items>
```

I want to extract some item codes based on criterias stored on that dictionary :

```
{ "info1", "LOREM" }
{ "info2", "IPSUM" }
```

I wrote that linq query :

```
var test =  from element in xml.Descendants("item").Elements()
        from param in dicoParams
        where param.Key == element.Name.ToString() && param.Value == element.Value
        select element.Parent.Attribute("code");
```

but the output is :

```
code="1"
code="1"
code="2"
code="3"
code="3"
```

and what I expected is :

```
code="1"
code="3"
```

We can notice that the query returned elements satisfying at least one condition, but I want it to satisfy both conditions.

How could I wrote that query ?

Comment: Why don't you expect `2`? It matches your criteria

Comment: Check your data. `item code="1"` matches both entries.

Comment: If you expect 2 answers then probably the Linq query should be based on the Dictionary, not on the XML.

Comment: @mattytommo Second item does not satisfy ALL conditions from dictionary.

Comment: @user1068352 I think you might be right, updated my answer to add that as an option as well.

Comment: yes, user1068352 is right. I want items matching all conditions. Sorry I misspoke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you expect `2` also, as `2` contains `info1` which contains `LOREM`.

Regardless, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
var test =  from element in xml.Descendants("item")
    from param in dicoParams
    where element.Elements()
        .Any(e => e.Name.ToString() == param.Key && e.Value == param.Value)
    select element.Attribute("code");
```

This will output only one code regardless of the number of matches.

**Actually, as @user1068352 mentions in the comments, it looks like you want items that match ALL items in the dictionary**.

If that's the case, try this:

```
var test = from element in xml.Descendants("item")
    where dicoParams.All(d => element.Elements
        .Any(e => e.Name.ToString() == d.Key && e.Value == d.Value))
    select element.Attribute("code");
```

Comment: You could probably be slight more efficient than the O(nm) of looping over all elements and all items in the dictionary, but I do think that the second answer is the the logic OP is after.

Comment: i executed that your answer both didn't return a result. pls check

Comment: You're my man ! Your second solution is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot, I struggled with that for hours

Comment: @Harkonnen I tried out the same, but i couldn't fetch the result. It's getting "Error 17 A local variable named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'e', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"

Comment: yes.. finally i found the solution. from element in xml.Descendants("item")
                       where dicoParams.All(d => element.Elements()
                           .Any(ee => ee.Name.ToString() == d.Key && ee.Value == d.Value))
                       select element.Attribute("code"); ee instead of e resolved that issue

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var test =
    from element in xml.Descendants("item")
    where element.Elements()
        .Any(x =>
            dicoParams.ContainsKey(x.Name.ToString())
            && dicoParams[x.Name.ToString()] == x.Value)
    select element.Attribute("code");
```

But as others have pointed out element "2" matches with the data you provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var test1 = (from element in elem.Descendants().Elements()
                         from item in val
                         where item.Key == element.Name.ToString() && item.Value == element.Value
                         select element.Parent.Attribute("code")).GroupBy(t => t.Parent.Attribute("code"));
```

you can just use group by too